# Run HTML file via Bash? Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, bash, websocket

I have a html file that when run in a browser such as Chrome and that contain javascript instructions, it sends the "emit" message to my websockets server and displays the value on that page.

Is there a way to call this same html file from a bash script as I'm wanting to insert data into a MySQL database which will ultimately call that html file to send an update to the websocket.

Hopefully that makes sense but hopefully there is a way to do it too :)

Comment: You could call it with `php` or another interpreter that executes `.html` (eg. `php file.html`).

Comment: I thought that myself, but when I run the `php file.html` it just seems to write the text to screen rather than running it. I'm wondering if I'm missing something from my php installation which isn't allowing it to run to command line

Comment: @RichardC the emit event is a javascript instruction isn't it ?

Comment: It is Javascript yes, but I need to "Import" the socket.io.js file into the same script I have created and my browser I'm having to use doesn't support the new Javascript import methods. So I'm writing as HTML which calls the Javascript, otherwise I would use nodejs

Comment: @RichardC So I guess you'll find a solution with my answer :p

Comment: @I'L'I the purpose of this question is to run js instruction inside an html side without using a browser I think. Not to rewrite thoses javascript instruction in other programming languages ;) . Otherwise we all can answer with something like "Why not just convert in Ruby|Perl|Python|Java"

Comment: @IdrissNeumann: That wasn't apparent until after the fact, duh. Maybe if that had been made apparent from the get go you wouldn't feel inclined to nit-pick commentary.

Comment: So I guess the question now would be, where in HTML I use `<script src="socket.io.js"></script>` to import a script from a common location, is that possible in a js file alone?

Comment: @RichardC you should read my answer. If you absolutly want to use an html file you can use something like phantomjs. But it's absolutly possible to use a socket.io client inside a node.js script and you should use `npm` to import the lib. (See my answer to get more details) => https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011390/2900196

Comment: @l'L'l Indeed, the question wasn't clear at first. But I asked about js because of the mention of `emit` and `websocket` inside the html (and it could only be running js inside html file to update the websocket).

Answer (score 0):

If you are only focused on rendering the HTML page (and not interacting with it via buttons or something) you may find this link helpful: [Running HTML from Command Line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58416/how-can-i-preview-html-documents-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute javascript instruction in your server without using a browser, I recommand you to use [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/) with a real js script without html.

Otherwise you can try to run an html file with js instruction inside using something like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) but I think is less performant than using Node correctly.

EDIT

> It is Javascript yes, but I need to "Import" the socket.io.js file into the same script I have created and my browser I'm having to use doesn't support the new Javascript import methods. So I'm writing as HTML which calls the Javascript, otherwise I would use nodejs

I think you can import the socket.io lib in node application using `npm`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

The documentation says that you can use a client inside a node script too :

> Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication. It consists in:
>
> - a Node.js server (this repository)
> - a Javascript client library for the browser (or a Node.js client)

Comment: Idriss, yes, I should have probably said in the beginning it is nodejs and socket.io that I am trying to use, but I'm quite new to it. I'm just getting to grips now on how to connect to my websocket that is already running and run that emit. Easy for pros, hard for us noobs.

Comment: @RichardC So have you tried one of those solutions? (node ​​or phantomjs). If you have a problem in particular do not hesitate to open a new question (with the error messages etc) and mark this one as resolved.